# How to create anchors or append items in aspx pages?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, image, hyperlink

I have some code I have written for a image gallery on my page, "gallery.aspx". The scenario is that I have an external aspx page with different links. When I click on one of those link I want to redirect to this image gallery but to a specific image.

For e.g I have a page called "home.aspx" with a link called "img2". When I click on "img2" I want to open up this image gallery(which sits on a page called "gallery.aspx"), but I want tab 2 of the gallery to be opened so 2nd image.

I can get it to work on my html pages using (url/gallery.html?img=img2) but I would really like to be able to do it on my sharepoint aspx page.

**Thank you in advance.**

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="gallery" align="center">
    <div class="thumbnails">
        <img name="ift" onclick="preview.src=img6.src" id="img6" src="IFT.png" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
        <img onclick="preview.src=img1.src" id="img1" src="Clear.png" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
        <img onclick="preview.src=img2.src" id="img2" src="Agile.png" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
        <img onclick="preview.src=img3.src" id="img3" src="AllForOne.png" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
        <img onclick="preview.src=img4.src" id="img4" src="Decide.png" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
        <img onclick="preview.src=img5.src" id="img5" src="Possibilities.png" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="preview" align="center">
        <img id="preview" src="IFT.png" alt="No Image Loaded"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Aspx also support HTML. You could just put these code to your ASPX page. No changes would be required.